# Login timeout handling in websphere commerce

Tags: authentication, timeout, websphere-commerce

In websphere commerce, when a session expires (login timeout occurs), where is the control transferred? Or to be more clear, what command calls the Logoff cmd?

the main problem is that the storeId parameter is not set before calling the Logoff cmd, which causes generic error page to be displayed

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem came from storeId and note other parameter ? Anyway, the code that calls the logoff is located int HTTP Adapter that is called in the RuntimeServletFilter, but I don't think it will help you with your case.

Check if the storeId has been set correctly before the time out, and if you can show us some traces it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested to know the class then read below,

The OOB class **LoginTimeoutHelper** has a method called **handleLoginTimeout**. This method checks for the session timeout and calls the logoffcmd and then the redirect is done by the logoffcmd.